how a JSON file can be given to Outline as a key in outline Android?
I am developing the mobile version of the Outline app, and I want to understand how to convert a JSON file into an Access Key.
I want the app to accept a JSON file containing the necessary configuration (server, method, password, etc.).
The JSON file should then be converted into an Outline-compatible Access Key to connect to the VPN server.
Example JSON file:
{ "server": "www.example.com", "server_port": 443, "method": "chacha20-ietf-poly1305", "password": "0MIZb3fhUNDzQBAW11D5Tr" } 
Are there libraries or tools within the Outline repository that handle this conversion?
I have reviewed the Outline GitHub repository but haven't gone through it entirely. It's possible that the functionality I need already exists and I overlooked it. So, If anyone familiar with the repository or its structure could point me to the relevant code or documentation, it would be very helpful.

One way to do it is to store the JSON content on your server, where Outline is running, and run an HTTP/HTTPS server on that server to fetch the JSON content from there. This will be a dynamic access key where you replace http with ssconf.
For example, if your server's IP is 1.2.3.4, then the link to the JSON file would look like http://1.2.3.4/key.json and you can replace http with ssconf so that it will be ssconf://1.2.3.4/key.json and use it as the key to the Outline app.
